# mkdir -p cannot create directory `/DirName': Permission denied

Tags: shell, permissions, mkdir

I'm trying to create a directory in a shell script:

mkdir -p DirName

but I always get the same error:
cannot create directory `/DirName': Permission denied

If I run the same command directly from the shell instead of using the scripts, that works perfectly.

any idea?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Check your current directory permissions. Seems like you are creating in / [root] and only root can create there. [script should run as root]. You should have googled this

Comment: yes, I googled it, but all the solutions I tried didn't work. anyway, thanks. I will try again.

Comment: Check the permissions on that script you are trying to run.

Comment: The error message implies you're trying to do `mkdir -p /DirName` which is different from `mkdir -p DirName`. The former tries to create a directory in the filesytem root (which you're likely not to have write permission to unless running as root). The latter creates a director in the current working dir.

Comment: and if you're specifying the directory name using a var in your script, make sure you quote your vars or you might end up with unexpected results if there are spaces in your dirnames.

Comment: actually my script says: mkdir -p /home/username/Documents/DirName. still a problem of permission?

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use the -p option, you need to specify the full path

```
mkdir -p /some/path/here/DirName
```

I suggest listing the full path (If you plan on your shell script to change locations).

If your shell script isn't going to change locations (you're not going to move it somewhere else later), I'd use:

```
mkdir ./DirName
```

These should all behave similarly to you creating the directory in the shell.

Comment: I am already using all path: mkdir -p /home/username/Documents/DirName

Comment: Does /home/username/Documents/ exist on root already?

Comment: For me mkdir -p some/path/here  is working, but mkdir -p /some/path/here is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a directory in the root of the filesystem (`/DirName`) instead of in the current directory (`Dirname` or `./Dirname`). You don't have access to write to the root.

Comment: ok actually my script gives all the path:                           mkdir -p /home/username/Documents/folder1/dirName

Comment: For me mkdir -p some/path/here  is working, but mkdir -p /some/path/here is not working.